# Provider notify other listeners from a ChangeNotifier

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have the following setup:

App with multiple pages: `VoltagesPage` & `TemperaturesPage`

I will receive some data over bluetooth serial like so:

bluetooth_data_provider.dart

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bluetooth_serial/flutter_bluetooth_serial.dart';

class BluetoothDataProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  String _data = '';
  String get data => _data;
  String _messageBuffer = '';

  BluetoothConnection? _connection;

  connectAndListen(String address) {
    BluetoothConnection.toAddress(address).then((connection) {
      print('Connected to the device');
      _connection = connection;

      if (_connection == null) {
        return;
      }

      _connection!.input!.listen(_onDataReceived).onDone(() {});
    }).catchError((error) {
      print('Cannot connect, exception occured');
      print(error);
    });
  }

  void _onDataReceived(Uint8List data) {
    String dataStr = ascii.decode(data);
    _messageBuffer += dataStr;

    if (dataStr.contains('\n')) {
      print(_messageBuffer);
      _data = _messageBuffer.substring(0, _messageBuffer.length - 1);
      _messageBuffer = '';

      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
}
```

This will notify all listeners, that listen to `BluetoothDataProvider`'s changes to its `data` field.

Now the `TemperaturesPage` is not really interested in a message, that is meant for the `VoltagesPage` and vice versa. I can identify who should receive the message by a prefix that is being sent by the device.

A voltage message can look like this:

`V:+12.5`

A temperature message can look like this:

`T:+45.6`

Right now when I'm watching the `BluetoothDataProvider`, from both of the pages, the widget has to decide whether to accept the message, or not. But this might leave a widget hanging, because it still needs to rebuild the widget as `build` is being called.

What I really want is something like this:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:typed_data';

import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bluetooth_serial/flutter_bluetooth_serial.dart';

class BluetoothDataProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  String _data = '';
  String get data => _data;
  String _messageBuffer = '';

  BluetoothConnection? _connection;

  connectAndListen(String address) {
    BluetoothConnection.toAddress(address).then((connection) {
      print('Connected to the device');
      _connection = connection;

      if (_connection == null) {
        return;
      }

      _connection!.input!.listen(_onDataReceived).onDone(() {});
    }).catchError((error) {
      print('Cannot connect, exception occured');
      print(error);
    });
  }

  void _onDataReceived(Uint8List data) {
    String dataStr = ascii.decode(data);
    _messageBuffer += dataStr;

    if (dataStr.contains('\n')) {
      print(_messageBuffer);
      _data = _messageBuffer.substring(0, _messageBuffer.length - 1);
      _messageBuffer = ''; 

      if(_data.startsWith("T:")) {
        // notify with a TemperatureProvider
      } else if (_data.startsWith("V:")){
        // notify with a VoltageProvider
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That way, each page could listen to a different Provider and only receive data they are actually interested in.

Is a scenario like this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this now.

In my main.dart, I will just create an instance of `BluetoothDataProvider` in `initState()` and providing the context from there to the constructor of `BluetoothDataProvider`.

After that, I am free to use the context to call different providers as follows:

```dart
void _onDataReceived(Uint8List data) {
  String dataStr = ascii.decode(data);
  _messageBuffer += dataStr;
  if (dataStr.contains('\n')) {
    print(_messageBuffer); // here you get complete string
    _data = _messageBuffer.substring(0, _messageBuffer.length - 1);
    _messageBuffer = ''; //clear buffer to accept new string
    var messageType = _data.substring(0, 2);

    switch (messageType) {
      case "V:":
        context.read<CurrentReceivedMessage>().setMessage(_data);
        break;
      case "T:":
        context.read<TemperatureReceivedMessage>().setMessage(_data);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use Selector.
Each page can listens to the data that they only interested in listening to.